# "pixel not pixel" and canvas, what the right way?

Tags: html, mobile, webkit, viewport, gecko

With removing target-densitydpi it pretty fu..n quest now. Major browsers scaling page in 1.5 times on my device (huawei honor android 4.0). How to prevent pixelization of canvas??

Answer (score 0):

May be it is due to your device is not preventing the browser to zoom in or out the screen according to the layout. Add a viewport meta tag in your head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width" />
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I want to prevent zoom, but I don't want pixelization in canvas. Ok, I set this viewport. If I add 100x100px image to canvas (with drawImage) browser scale it to 150x150px and show me with pixelization. The people who are promoting brand new "Responsive Site Design", how they work with canvas?

Comment: Give that canvas a class or id (example-canvas) or whatever you like and define its CSS properties in the stylesheet as #canvas{width: 70% !important;} Note- important is required .Define it for every viewport/mediaqueries. Up till now for canvas only this hack is available in css.